# setting password with wd security on a hard drive that already contains data

Tags: hard-drive, security, external-hard-drive, password-protection

I have a wd my passport hard drive (5 TB) that already contains 1 TB of data.  Does installing wd security and setting password format the HDD?  Does hardware encryption reduce transfer speed and HDD lifespan?

Comment: You really should avoid using the Western Digital Encryption option, you are better off, using BitLocker or VeraCrypt.

Comment: You should be able to enable security at any point, the drive is *always* encrypted anyways.